# how to read the max value from sql table then pass into the querystring in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to do my service order which is after typing in some information then direct to a next page can select the technician. I try to request the querystring = service orderID, So I can insert the technicianID into the table. how can i read the service orderID from the database and then pass into the querystring?

Response.Redirect("~/AddEditServiceOrder/AssignService.aspx?id=" & serviceid)

Comment: Start with this article from Microsoft: [How to: Create and Execute an SQL Statement that Returns Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL might look something like this (with the necessary Declares)

```
INSERT INTO Orders
           (VendorID, [Date], Subtotal, Discount, Freight, Total, CupCost)
VALUES     (@VendorID,@Date,@Subtotal,@Discount,@Freight,@Total, @CupCost);

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Then in the VB Code

```
Dim itgOrderID As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
```

This will get you the Primary Key of the newly inserted service order so you can find it and do an update with the technician ID.